# how to make my program accept a different number of passed command line arguments in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python so sorry if my question is vague, I am writing a program that takes 3 parsed arguments from the command line but it can take an optional fourth argument (word) if the user enters it. However, I ran into the issue that when I add the fourth parsed argument into "main" then I enter 3 arguments, I get an error message that one argument is missing. How can I make that fourth argument optional? I tried setting to False by default. I also tried to enter nargs='*' but none worked.

Here is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filesdir")
    parser.add_argument("classname")
    parser.add_argument("feature")
    parser.add_argument("word")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: have you tried  *args

Comment: I used it with the function I call. I will try to find a way to use it with the passed cmd arguments. Thanks!